# Can .NET datatable visualizer be launched from code?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I have several datatable/dataset visualizers installed in my Visual Studio 2008. Launching a visualizer manually in the IDE is a bit time consuming. While debugging, I would like to display a datatable visualizer with a datatable's data automatically through code.

I want to put a breakpoint on the line after invoking the visualizer. I know the visualizer window is modal but that's OK during debugging.

Is this possible?

(The other route which I might consider, if above is not possible, is to display a grid with the data in a winform window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just a `DataGridView` ?

```
using(Form form = new Form())
using(DataGridView grid = new DataGridView()) {
   grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
   grid.DataSource = table;
   form.Controls.Add(grid);
   form.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why the first (only) column width is not changing.

form.ShowDialog(this);
grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
grid.Refresh();